# Can I reference environment variables in my SQL script in a Spring Boot app? How?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, testing

Suppose, I have a script like this

```sql
INSERT INTO permissions(id, name, created_date, modified_date)
VALUES (1, 'ADMIN', current_timestamp, current_timestamp),
       (2, 'MODERATOR', current_timestamp, current_timestamp),
       (3, 'USER', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO accounts(id, username, password, enabled, created_date, modified_date)
VALUES (1, 'mickey_m', '$2y$10$ZdqfOo1vwdHJJGnkmGrw/OUelZcU9ZfRFaX/RMN3XniXH96eTkB1e', true, current_timestamp,
        current_timestamp),
    (2, 'minerva_m', '$2y$10$PiZxGGi904rCLdTSGY1ycuQhcEtQrP1u74KvQ2IEuk5Jh18Ml.6xO', true, current_timestamp,
     current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO accounts_permissions(account_id, permission_id)
VALUES (1, 3),
       (2, 3);
    <!-- and so on -->
```

I may then, for example, use it in an `@Sql` annotation

```sql
    @Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "CreateCommentTest/before.sql")
    @Sql(executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "CreateCommentTest/after.sql")
    @Test
    public void createCommentTest() throws Exception {
```

The values in the script are hard-coded, e.g. usernames, passwords. It's relatively straightforward to reference a properties file's keys in a Java file, though it's less clear to me how I can do the same thing in an SQL file. Perfunctory googling or searching on SO didn't help

**How do I do it (if it's possible)?**

Comment: What wrong with using env vars to set query params?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm not sure what you mean. You can use env variables to set query params, but I'm talking SQL scripts